# Should simple radical extensions be normal?

Tags: galois-theory

I am reading about simple radical extensions and I have a question. Does a simple radical extension need to be normal? I can't think of an argument to support this claim but I can't come up with a counterexample either.

Comment: Is the canonical example of a nonnormal extension, the result of adjoining the real cube root of 2 to Q, normal?